# Configure Spring @DataJpaTest with custom base repository

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-boot-test

Let's assume a custom base [JpaRepository](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/JpaRepository.html) implementation like the following.

```
public class SimpleCustomJpaRepository<T, ID extends Serializable> extends SimpleJpaRepository<T, ID> implements CustomJpaRepository<T, ID> {

    @Override
    public List<T> findAllCustom() {

        ...
    }
}
```

The base repository is registered using the `@EnableJpaRepositories` annotation.

```
@EnableJpaRepositories(value = "org.somebody.repository", repositoryBaseClass = SimpleCustomJpaRepository.class)
```

How should I configure a integration test for the `UserRepository` that's extending the `CustomJpaRepository` interface and should therefor use the custom base implementation?

```
public interface UserRepository extends CustomJpaRepository<User, Long> { ... }
```

The currently used integration test fails with `org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property findAllCustom found for type User!`. Actually it failed to load the `ApplicationContext` because my custom base repository implementation is not registered during integration test and therefor no implementation for `findAllCustom` was found.

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@DataJpaTest
class UserRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository. 
}
```

How should I register a custom `JpaRepository` implementation in combination with a JPA repository integration test?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I still can't explain the cause of the problem, but manually configuring the JPA has solved my problem.

```
@TestConfiguration
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {JpaRepositoriesAutoConfiguration.class})
@EnableJpaRepositories(value = "org.somebody.repository", repositoryBaseClass = SimpleCustomJpaRepository.class)
public class JpaTestConfig {

    ...
}
```

I just imported this additional configuration class in my tests and it works like a charm.

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@DataJpaTest
@Import(JpaTestConfig.class)
class UserRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository. 
}
```

Comment: If I could upvote you 1000 times, I would take the time for it. No mention about this in documentation, does not work out of box, and I even try to take same path as you did, but failed somewhere and my TestConfig did not work for me. Your worked as a charm. THANKS a LOT!

Comment: I have just spent 8 hours trusting Spring reference and going through the tutorials. Nothing about it, though it really helps. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The constructor of SimpleCustomJpaRepository should look like:

```
public class SimpleCustomJpaRepository<T, ID extends Serializable> extends SimpleJpaRepository<T, ID> implements CustomJpaRepository<T, ID> {

    private final EntityManager entityManager;

    public SimpleCustomJpaRepository(JpaEntityInformation entityInformation, EntityManager entityManager) {
        super(entityInformation, entityManager);
        this.entityManager = entityManager;
    }

    @Override
    public List<T> findAllCustom() {

        ...
    }
}
```

Additionally, make sure that interface CustomJpaRepository is annotated with:

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface CustomJpaRepository<T, ID extends Serializable> extends JpaRepository<T, ID> {
    List<T> findAllCustom();
}
```

Comment: Sure both of them applies to my implementation... Should it automatically include my `@EnableJpaRepository` config? I would guess that my custom base repository is never detected in the test environment

Comment: Where your @EnableJpaRepositories annotation is located? Can you paste your config?

Comment: Add also stacktrace please